# USER_HOME for grails on Windows

Tags: grails

Does anyone know how to set the USER_HOME on windows so that when I create an app it's not created inside 'Documents and Settings'.  I know how to override it inside the app but I want to change it so that it defaults to a certain folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the user home is defined by Java system property user.home. Using the following groovy code you can get it:

System.getProperties('user.home')

By using System.setProperty(key, value) you can set USER_HOME as you want.